# Add key value pair to php associative array from Database

Tags: php, arrays

DB is set up as such:

[image]

```
include 'php/DbConnect.php';
$sql = $mysqli->query(
 "SELECT t.*, v.* 
 FROM task t 
 INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
 INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
 WHERE vt.taskid = 1");
$wordsArray = array();  


while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {

   // echo "<br> " . $row['taskname'] . ": ".  $row['chinese'] . " : " . $row['english'];
    $wordsArray['chinese']['english'] = $row['chinese'];
    echo $wordsArray['chinese']['english'];
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Output: `Ni Ta Wo`

Desired output: `Ni: You` `Ta: Him` `Wo: I`

I want the Chinese word (key) and associated English translation (value) loaded into wordsArray, but don't know the correct syntax to load and to access.

Thanks

Comment: well first tell us where is the key, are you have them in db ?

Comment: @PRAISER edited above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want this? It maps one direction, Chinese to English, but there's not a really great way to do bidirection mapping as far as I know. (Typically I use two mappings to do that.) edit: It seems this is the direction you want, based on your edit.

```
$wordsArray = array();
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);  
var_dump($wordArray);
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I echo out the k v pair?

Comment: actually `echo "<br>".key($wordsArray) . ":" . $wordsArray[$row['chinese']];` was only outputting the same `Ni` as the key for each unique english value

Comment: Oh, for output: `echo $row['chinese'] . ": " . $wordsArray[$row['chinese']];` There's not a more straight-forward way to ensure the keys are right, so I put a var_dump in my example, which can show the structure of the assoc. array.

Comment: Okay so I can't directly output the key from the $wordsArray... that's weird.. lol

Comment: So now I want to use them on the client side... so I did `var words = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $wordsArray).'"' ?>];` to load them into JS array, then  `$.each(words, function(key, value) { console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);....` which outputs numbers for the keys: `0, You`, `1, Him or Her`, and not the Chinese word. Why is that?

Comment: best way to send this kind of data to client is to put them in an array and send them as jSON with `json_encode` function, it includes the key & values.

Comment: @PRAISER can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = array();
foreach (...) {
    $json[$row['chinese']] = $row['english']
}

$return_result = json_encode($json);

echo $return_result;
```

you may grab that return value with `jQuery` and parse it as jSON with `jQuery.parseJSON()` with/without ajax.

update, if you don't want parse the data with ajax just add the result to the page within a `script` tag like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    var data = '<?php echo $return_result; ?>';
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(json);
})(jQuery);
</script>
```